# How to update an entity with Google App Engine Java with JPA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm trying to update an entity using JPA with Google App Engine. I start a transaction, retrieve the entity to update, change a few fields, call persist and commit. Everything is executed without any error, however, the entity is not modified.

Here is the sample code:

```
EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
try {
        tx.begin();
        DomainName domain = entityManager.find(DomainName.class, domainName);
        domain.setExists(body != null);
        domain.setHttpBody(body);
        domain.setHttpTimeStamp(new Date());
        entityManager.persist(domain);
        tx.commit();
} finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
        }
}
```

What should I do to persist the entity using JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what the persist() call is doing, since the object (if found, which you don't tell us) will be in managed state, hence the first update of a field marks the object as dirty, and will be committed on the commit() call. Obviously a simple inspection of the log would tell you what was happening.

Comment: the object is found, I've also stepped through the code, inspected the retrieved object and looked ok, there are not exceptions in the log.

Comment: I think I got it, I was actually using two different entity managers (wired by Spring in two different objects) and when I wrote the sample code, I simplified it. So in practice you're saying that my sample code is correct and should work. I am going to fix the real program, I am confident that will work then.

Comment: Ok, great, it works perfectly. Thank you for confirming that what I was doing in the sample code was OK. So the lesson to take home for me, is to use only one EntityManager in a transaction.